# How to create entities dynamically in android room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am looking to create entities dynamically in room-database because I want to create entities according to this data, the below data will come from the backend

i) attributeName 
ii)dataType

Comment: So basically u want to create table with these column names in room???

Comment: I will get a list of attributes name & data type from the backend 

These attributes name & data type are dynamic

ex: {"name":" jack"}

{"firstName":"Antony","lastName":"bruce"}

like this I will get the number of items dynamically, according to that I need to create entities dynamically in the android database

Comment: column nd table name is constant ?

Comment: Here nothing is static everything dynamic